# Run and manage android application on hundreds of identical devices

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to upload a single apk to each identical phones. I need to manage multiple settings in the phone and also need to re upload the new apk for upgrades again to the same hundreds of devices. I am spending lot of time for this work.
We are using Xamarin for android app development.
List of things to change in the settings.
1.Enabling the other sources to upload the apk.
2.Permissions to access wifii, bluetooth and cellular data.
3.Moving the app icon to main screen or home  screen.

Can anyone provide an easy way to manage this?

Comment: Are those phones scattered around the world?

Comment: Have you looked into ADB scripting?

Comment: @greenapps Yes, the mobiles are scattered around different places.

Comment: What more you did not tell that could be relevant?

Comment: @Sirens I didn't look into ADB scripting. Do you think it can minimizing the time spent on changing the settings ?

Comment: Yeah, ADB can set settings. You need to explain what you need to do or else we can't help you. There are thousands of things you may want to configure

Comment: thanks,I have added few more details in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution do not exist, however exists MDM system. I used it 7 years ago for Win mobile and Palms. It worked like a charm. Or if you want do it all by yourself check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

What is MDM? [Source](http://www.zdnet.com/article/mdm-for-android-devices-what-your-business-needs-to-know/)

MDM is an industry term associated with the management of mobile devices (most often it is applied to large-scale management) and involves a third-party solution that serves as the centralized management console for the devices. With these third-party solutions you are able to handle tasks that include:

- Distributing applications;
- Locking or wiping a single device;
- Sending software updates;
- Remotely troubleshooting a device;
- Pushing out settings and content;
- Enforcing policy compliance across platforms;
- Managing device lifecycles;
- Detecting jailbroken or rooted devices;
- Encrypting sensitive data;
- Monitoring usage;
- Containerization.

Comment: ALexgs Yes this provides a better way to accomplish. But  the mobiles I have been using are kitkat versions. MDM supports from lollipop it seems. Can you provide any other alternative if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @Avinash Reddy Chintareddy 
Unfortunately I do not know any other solution, However I did a litle research and I found this MDM that work with android 4.0 to 7.1.1 https://dm.comodo.com/solutions/mdm-for-android/

Other option is you register all devices on google play store for private apps https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en